# Should I implement all the methods present in an abstract class?

Tags: java, oop

Below is the code snippet:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

    public abstract void a();
    public abstract void b();
}


public class Foo extends MyAbstractClass {

    public void a() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public void b(){
        System.out.println("bye");
    }
}


public class Bar extends MyAbstractClass {

    public void a() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public void delta() {
        System.out.println("gamma");
    }
}
```

There are couple of questions that I have:

**Q-1 :- Should I implement ALL the methods in `abstract` class?**

**Q-2 :- Can the implementing class have its own methods?**

Comment: The `bar` class will not compile as it is currently written because it is not abstract and does not implement `b`.

Comment: Not strictly related, but in C++, if you are dealing with abstract classes, you don't  need to do it.

Comment: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/cMDbSy9cWa Check it out if you like

Answer (score 70):

When you extend an `Interface` or an `Abstract` class you are creating a contract of sorts with that `superclass`. In the contract you are saying:

> "I will implement all unimplemented methods in my superclass"

If you do not, implement all the unimplemented methods, then you are breaking your contract. A way to not break your contract is make your subclass `Abstract` as well as a way of saying

> "I have not implemented all the methods in my contract, I am going to
> have my subclasses implement them".

For your class `bar` right now, you must implement `b()` or make `bar` an `Abstract` class or you are not fulfilling your contract with `MyAbstractClass`

The basic idea is:

**Interface:** None of my methods are implemented. A subclass must implement all my methods in order to implement me. (Note: I believe default interfaces have been added to Java 8 which may change this a bit)

Example:

```
 public interface myInterface
 { 
     //My subclasses must implement this to fulfill their contract with me
     public void methodA();
 
     //My subclasses must implement this to fulfill their contract with me
     public void methodB();
 }
```

**Abstract:** I may implement some of my methods, but I will also leave methods as abstract so that my subclasses must implement because they can implement those classes to suit their needs better than I can.

Example:

```
 public abstract class myAbstractClass
 {
     //My subclasses must implement this to fulfill their contract with me
     public abstract void methodC();

     public void helloWorld()
     {
         System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
 }
```

`Abstract` classes can also extend interfaces so they can implement some of their methods. But they can also leave some of the methods unimplemented so the subclass can implement them. If you leave an interface method unimplemented, there is not need to declare it abstract, it is already in the contract.

Example:

```
  public abstract class myAbstractClass2 implement myInterface
  {
      @Override
      public void methodA()
      {
          // this fulfills part of the contract with myInterface.
          // my subclasses will not need to implement this unless they want to override
          // my implementation.
      }

      //My subclasses must implement this to fulfill their contract with me
      public abstract void methodD();
  }
```

So in essence, an abstract class doesn't have as strict a contract with it's superclass because it can delegate its methods to its subclasses.

**Regular Class**: (I use regular to mean non-interface, and non-abstract). I must implement **all** unimplemented methods from all of my superclasses. These classes have a binding contract.

Example:

```
 public class mySubClass extends myAbstractClass2
 {
     @Override
     public void methodB()
     {
         //must be implemented to fulfill contract with myInterface
     }

     @Override
     public void methodD()
     {
         //must be implemented to fulfill contract with myAbstractClass2
     }

     public void myMethod()
     {
        //This is a method specifically for mySubClass. 
     }
 }
```

Comment: You my friend deserve a big up for this explanation. Thank you and God bless you!

Answer (score 27):

***Q-1:- Should I implement all methods in `abstract` class?***

- Yes, you **must** implement all `abstract` methods.

***Q-2 :- Can the implementing class have its own methods?***

- Yes, you can declare own (*more specfic*) methods.

Answer (score 11):

You not only *should*, but **have to** implement all abstract methods (if the subclass is non-abstract). Otherwise an object of that subclass wouldn't know what to do if that method was called!

The only way to prevent this is if the subclass is also declared `abstract`, so that it cannot be instantiated in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to implement all methods of an abstract class. **But you must implement all abstract methods of it.**

In fact extending an abstract class has no difference then extending a normal class. It's not like implementing interfaces. Since you're extending you are creating a subclass thus you can add as many methods and attributes as you need.

Comment: This answer is more precise than the others.

Answer (score 3):

Ya definately implementing class can define its own method as well and if are not implementing all the methods of your abstract class in the derived class then mark this derived class also as Abstract

but at the end of chain you have to make one concrete class which implements all the method that was not implement in abstract sub-parent

Answer (score 3):

```
    public interface I{
       public void m();
    }

    public abstract class A1 implements I{
         //No need to implement m() here - since this is abstract
    }

    public class B1 extends A1{
      public void m(){
            //This is required, since A1 did not implement m().
      }
    }

    public abstract class A11 extends A1{
          //Again No need to implement m() here - since this is abstract
         public abstract void newA11Method()
    }

   public class B11 extends A11{
        //This class needs to implement m() and newA11Method()
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the implementing class need only implement the methods labeled as abstract in the abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you must implement all the **abstract** methods present in an abstract class. As the purpose of abstract class is purely to create a template for the functions whose implementation is decided by the class implementing them. So if you don't implement them, then you are breaking the concept of abstract class. But you ***don't have*** to implement the **non-abstract methods** of the Abstract Class (but you can override them to add another suitable implementation) because it has an implementation already.

To answer your second question,  yes you can create any number of your own methods irrespective of the abstract class you are extending.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you extends abstract you should give implementation for all [abstract methods](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-use-of-abstract-methods-in-Java) which are presents in [abstract class](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/abstract-classes-in-java/). Othrewise you should make it implementation class as abtract class.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement all the abstract methods you have in the abstract class. But you can directly use the concrete methods that are implemented.

For more information please refer to the :
https://www.javatpoint.com/abstract-class-in-java

Answer (score -1):

Yes, When you are implementing an Interface **you will have** to implement all its methods (unless the `default` method in Java 8 and later). That is the purpose of defining an Interface. And yes, you can have your own methods in the implementing class where you implement an Interface.